# Return multiple columns with SQL where GroupBy is on one column

Tags: sql

I have noticed that all the columns in a SQL Select Query should be in a aggregate function, because otherwise the output value for group would be arbitrary.

This makes sense. But when the other columns are same in value, it doesn't matter which is returned. Is there a way to specify this or just use MAX() or MIN() on varchar columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to aggregate one or more columns that need to be displayed, include them in the column list of your query and the columns to group by list too.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3) AS Col3Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
ORDER BY Col1, Col2;
```

In the above example, data from `Col3` is summed using the combined data of `Col1` and `Col2` to determine where the aggregation is segregated. In other words, when the value of either `Col1` or `Col2` changes, a new bucket for a running sum of `Col3` is created. You output data could look like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3Total
====  ====  =========
A     A     4
A     B     97
B     A     1
B     B     NULL - assumes a NULL value was found in the Col3 data
B     C     2
```

If you want to assume that `Col2` has a single matching value per distinct `Col1`, it would like something like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3Total
====  ====  =========
A     Y     101
B     Z     NULL - assumes a NULL value was found in the Col3 data
```

[Microsoft TSQL SUM function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

[Oracle SQL Aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

[MySQL SQL Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: What if I want only Col1 to be distinct? That was my actual scenario that lead me to re-think this.

Comment: Assuming a slightly different data set where the combination of ``Col1`` and ``Col2`` are distinct, you would get data similar to the second output.

Answer (score 1):

> But when the other columns are *same in value*, it doesn't matter which is returned.

I'd agree with that.

Some DBMSs implement "aggregate" functions like FIRST and LAST to keep the "purity" of the select statement but, if the values really *are* the same, then it should make no difference at all and MIN or MAX will do just as well.

Of course, you can never *guarantee* that they're going to *stay* the same ...